# php Building inbox chat

Tags: php, mysql

i'm Building inbox chat And I have a little problem

It's my DB

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chat` (
  `cfrom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `sent` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `recd` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And my code:

```
$from=$_GET['MyUserId'];
$chat_all_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE cfrom='{$from}' OR cto='{$from}'")or die(mysql_error());
while($chat = mysql_fetch_array($chat_all_query)){

    if($chat['cfrom']==$from){
        echo $chat['cto'].'<br />';
    }else{
        echo $chat['cfrom'].'<br />';
    }

}
```

The problem it presents me the users have a conversation with a double amount of times sent him a message or I sent him

It seems to me that if there is an option to `group by` to `if` it would be good Or otherwise does not appear to me the few times

Can you help?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid duplicate display of to or from address?

Comment: Yes! Just like that :)

Comment: help me, Please, someone?

Comment: Not clear with "The problem it presents me the users have a conversation with a double amount of times sent him a message or I sent him" part.

Comment: This screenshot of my inbox
I have a conversation with sarit, ora and itzik
I'm looking for a way to reduce this double display

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0DyZu9UNoYIajFVUU41cXlXc3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can't access the document

Comment: oops Sorry :)
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0DyZu9UNoYIajFVUU41cXlXc3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Not sure, you could do much within the query except grouping by from and timestamp. `recd` is the time at which message was received? if so you could `group by cfrom, recd`. Try and let me know.

Comment: If I have

cfrom = '{$ from}' group by cto OR cto = '{$ from}'' group by cfrom

But it can not be

Comment: Then you could simply have a temp var within the loop and check if previous value is same as current values, if so, skip. You can use timestamp, message and from/to to identify unique ones.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand, can you give me an example?

Comment: From what I've understood from your question, the following should help.

    `$from = '';
    $msg = '';
    $recd = 0;
    while($chat = mysql_fetch_array($chat_all_query)){
    
        if($chat['cfrom']==$from){
            echo $chat['cto'].'<br />';
        }else{
          if( $chat['cfrom']!=$from || $chat['message']!=$msg || $chat['recd']!=$recd  )
            echo $chat['cfrom'].'<br />';
        }
    
      $from = $chat['cfrom'];
      $msg = $chat['message'];
      $recd = $chat['recd'];
    }`

Comment: I still have duplicate users